# Selecting a class function as an argument

Tags: python, function, class

So in my class I want to select a function to use as my activation function as an argument. Currently I do this through

```
class NeuralNetworks:
    def __init(self, n_inputs, layer_vector, func='sig'):
        (...)
        self.func = func

    def sigmoid(self, x):
         (...)

    def reLu(self, x):
         (...)

    def propagate(...):
         (...)
         if self.func == 'sig':
             (...)
         else:
             (...)

         (...)

         if self.func == 'sig':
             (...)
         else:
             (...)

         (and so on...)
```

All the if/else statements end up making the code pretty verbose, is there a neater way to select the function?

Comment: If you want to get function name in some variable and then execute it, then please check 'getattr'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function in question is external to the class, you can simply pass in the function

```
def somefunc(parm1, parm2):
    pass

nn = NeuralNetworks(inputs, vector, somefunc)
```

If the "function" is a method on the class, then you can store all the alternatives in a `dict` and access them from there:

```
class NeuralNetworks:
    def __init__(self, n_inputs, layer_vector, func='sig'):
        (...)
        self.funcdict = {'sig' : self.sigmoid,
                         'relu' : self.reLu,
                         'other': self.otherfunc}
        self.func = func

    def sigmoid(self, x):
        (...)

    def reLu(self, x):
         (...)

    def propagate(...):
         (...)
#         if self.func == 'sig':
#             (...)
#         else:
#             (...)
         self.funcdict[self.func](x)
```

If the methods take different parameters, then it gets a little more complicated.

Comment: Ah, neat that you can send in a function like that, much more convenient than having it within the class, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're aiming for?

```
class NeuralNetworks:

    def __init__(self, func='sigmoid'):
        self.func = getattr(self, func)

    def sigmoid(self, x):
        print('sigmoid()', x)

    def reLu(self, x):
        print('reLu()', x)

    def propagate(self, x):
         self.func(x)

NeuralNetworks().propagate(123)
NeuralNetworks(func = 'reLu').propagate(456)
```